# Динамический массив и считывание из файла не работают вместе

Tags: отладка, массивы, memory, c++, компилятор

Вопрос на фундаментальном уровне от начинающего.
Вот такой код:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int *test = new int[];
    ifstream f("ofile.txt");
    for (int i=0,v; i<10; i++)
    {
        f>>v;
        test[i]=1; 
        cout<<"\nv = "<<v<<", i = "<<i<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

При компиляции выдаёт такое сообщение:

[image]

вероятно (поправьте меня, если ошибаюсь) это говорит об ошибке обращения к памяти. Но детали мне не ясны. 
Если убираю или вывод из файла, или массив, всё работает.
Буду признателен за разъяснение.

UPD. Конечная цель в данном случае - сохранить в массиве контент считываемого файла. Проблема в том, что количество строк в нём может быть не известно заранее.

**UPD 2.** Ошибки при попытке применить последнее решение.
[image]

Comment: А что вот это может означать?

     int *test = new int[];

Возможно там д.б.

     int *test = new int[10];

Comment: Если на *фундаментальном уровне*, то нормальный компилятор, такую конструкцию

    int *test = new int[];

вообще, считает ошибочной


    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ cat testx.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    
    int main(int ac, char *av[])
    {
      int *test = new int[];
    }
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ testx.cpp
    testx.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
    testx.cpp:5:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ 

Для обучения смените среду программирования.

Comment: Какая у вас версия Visual Studio? Ваш код тупо не должен компилироваться, попробуйте Rebuild.

Comment: @srgg67, попробуйте использовать крестовый `vector<int>`.


      int v;
      vector<int> test;
    
      while (in.good()) {
        in >> v;
        if (in.good()) 
          test.push_back(v);
      }

если очень хочется с указателями, то в Си стиле


    #define INCR  10
    ...
    
      int capacity = 0, size = 0, *test = 0;
    
      do {
        if (size + 1 > capacity)
          test = (typeof(test))realloc(test, sizeof(*test) * (capacity += INCR));
        in >> test[size++];
      } while (in.good());
      --size;
    
(см. `man 3 realloc` (можно через гугл)).

Comment: Понимаете, мне нужно в конечном итоге просто сохранить цифры из файла в массиве. Длина файла мне неизвестна, поэтому подставить её при инициализации массива я не могу. Наверняка решение достаточно простое.

Comment: @srgg67, вот и используйте `std::vector` - это и массив, и всю муть с выделением памяти и изменением размера он прячет в себя...

Comment: @srgg67, а в известном смысле массив и указатель эквивалентны.

Я вам предложил 2 варианта, как прочесть неизвестное заранее количество чисел из файла. Далее с ними можно обращаться (синтаксически), как с элементами массива.

Что не устраивает? Задавайте вопросы.

--

Кстати, в комментарии Вы пишете, что надо прочесть из файла *цифры*. Уточните задачу и формат файла.

Comment: Конечная цель в данном случае - сохранить в массиве контент считываемого файла. Проблема в том, что количество строк в нём может быть НЕ ИЗВЕСТНА заранее. Пожалуйста, приведите пример работающего кода и закроем вопрос.

Comment: @srgg67 ну Вы даёте. Берём код от @avp

     #include <iostream>
     #include <vector>
     #include <fstream>
     using namespace std;
     int main() {
       int v;
       vector<int> test;
       ifstream f("ofile.txt");

       while (f >> v)
         test.push_back(v);
       for(vector<int>::iterator it=test.begin(); it != test.end(); it++) cout << *it << ' ';
       cout << endl;
       return 0;
     }

Содержимое файла ofile.txt -- по вкусу.

Answer (score 4):

Если Вам надо прочесть все содержимое файла в память, то на мой взгляд 
это стоит оформить в виде функции

```
char *file_get_contents (const char *filename, size_t *filesize);
```

которая получает имя файла и возвращает его содержимое в динамической памяти, выделяемой `malloc()`, а по указателю filesize размещает размер прочитанного файла.
При ошибках или нулевой длине файла, возвращается NULL. Конкретная причина ошибки в переменной `errno` (собственно, как обычно).

```
// filegc.c   g++/gcc filegc.c  ./a.out filename
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

char *
file_get_contents (const char *name, size_t *size)
{
  int fd = open(name ? name : "", O_RDONLY);
  char *data = 0;
  *size = 0;

  if (fd >= 0) {
    struct stat st;
    fstat(fd, &st);
    if (*size = st.st_size) 
      if (data = (char *)malloc(st.st_size))
        read(fd, data, *size);
    close(fd);
  }

  return data;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  size_t filesize;
  char *fdata = file_get_contents(av[1], &filesize);

  if (!fdata)
    perror("file_get_contents");
  else
    printf("read %ld bytes\n", (long)filesize);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Хотя, поразмышляв немного, я подумал, что вот в таком виде

```
char *
file_get_contents (const char *name, size_t *size)
{
  int fd = open(name ? name : "", O_RDONLY);
  char *data = 0;
  *size = 0;

  if (fd >= 0) {
    struct stat st;
    fstat(fd, &st);
    if (data = (char *)malloc((*size = st.st_size) + 1)) {
      read(fd, data, *size);
      data[*size] = 0;
    }
    close(fd);
  }

  return data;
}
```

функцией будет пользоваться удобней (все же, почти наверняка, ее будут вызывать для работы с *текстом* файла).

Поэтому запишем в память 0 после данных файла  (для пустого файла будем возвращать  пустую строку, а не NULL).

А если Вы предпочитаете иметь дело с крестовыми контейнерами, то вот аналогичный вариант с std::string

```
#include  <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

using namespace std;
string 
file_get_contents (const char *name)
{
  string result;
  int fd = open(name ? name : "", O_RDONLY);

  if (fd >= 0) {
    int l, bs;
    char data[bs = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)];
    struct stat st;

    fstat(fd, &st);
    if (st.st_size)
      result.reserve(st.st_size);
    while (l = read(fd, data, bs))
      result.append((const char *)data, l);
    close(fd);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Надеюсь, `main()` к нему сами напишите?

И наконец (если эффективность обработки **больших файлов** Вас не волнует), *чисто крестовый* вариант

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out filestr.cpp
file: filestr.cpp (607 bytes)  contains 29 lines
// filestr.cpp  read file in memory as vector of lines
#include  <iostream>
#include  <fstream>
#include  <vector>
#include  <cerrno>
#include  <cstring>

using namespace std;
int main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  fstream in(av[1] ? av[1] : "");
  string s;
  vector<string> file;
  size_t sum = 0;

  if (in.good()) {
    while(getline(in, s)) {
      file.push_back(s);
      sum += s.size();
    }

    cout << "file: " << av[1] << " (" << sum << " bytes) "
         << " contains " << file.size() << " lines\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < file.size(); i++)
      cout << file[i] << '\n';
  } else {
    cerr << strerror(errno) << '\n';
  }
}
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

С наступающим Новым Годом!

Comment: Чего-то в вашем коде не хватает - см. UPD2. Я не вижу, где оно обращается к файлу по имени. Вероятно, я не понимаю какой-то простейшей вещи (которую вы считаете само собой разумеющейся), но я ведь и предупреждал - что новичок. Давайте представим, что у нас есть файл по имени ofile.txt. PS. Си-шники, наск. я знаю, так скобки обычно не расставляют (это нейтральное замечание, не более). Из Java пришли или откуда-то ещё?

Comment: @srgg67, это как раз-таки типичный для C K&R стиль.

Comment: > Я не вижу, где оно обращается к файлу по имени.

`fstream in(av[1] ? av[1] : "");` — из чего следует, что путь к файлу ожидается первым аргументом командной строки.

Comment: @srgg67, для чтения по умолчанию  файла `"ofile.txt"` (запуск программы без аргументов) просто напишите в

    fstream in(av[1] ? av[1] : "ofile.txt");

и измените в списке `main()` `argv` на `av` (или наоборот, в тексте программы `av` на `argv`).

По поводу простейших вещей -- Вы правы. Для начала советую внимательно почитать [K&R](http://os24.org/files/books/Brian_Kernighan_Dennis_Ritchie-The_C_Programming_Language-RU.pdf).

И смените систему (думаю проблема с `getline()` в этом). Если уж совсем не можете без винды, то поставьте в нее хотя бы MinGW.

А про скобочки -- места мало.

Comment: Позвольте поделиться с вами одним наблюдением. Вот оно: профессионал всегда предлагает работающее решение. Остальные советуют "читать и учиться". Вот вам пример первого (тот же самый вопрос): http://stackoverflow.com/a/20824971/1522479

Comment: @srgg67, то что я не профессиональный **преподаватель** Вы угадали.

--

Кто же мог представить, что код (предложенный Вам вчера)

    int v;
    vector<int> test;

    while (in >> v)
      test.push_back(v);

просто непостижим для Вас. 

После этого (особенно после комментария "Конечная цель в данном случае - сохранить в массиве **контент считываемого файла**. Проблема в том, что количество строк в нём может быть НЕ ИЗВЕСТНА заранее.") уже начались игры в угадайку.

--

Конечно, логика дилетанта это нечто особенное ..., но постарайтесь в будущем выражать свои мысли по-яснее.

Answer (score 2):

```
int *test = new int[];
```

Эта строка эквивалентна следующей

```
int *test = new int;
```

Создается только **один** элемент, из-за чего на **второй** итерации цикла чтения программа падает при обращении к **несуществующему** элементу.

Необходимо либо выделять память с избытком (в вашем случае достаточно даже статически):

```
int test[777];
```

либо, раз уж мы пишем на С++, использовать динамический массив std::vector.

```
#include <vector>
...

std::vector<int> test; // Объявляем
...
test.push_back(1); // Добавляем элемент
...
// Читаем значения
for (int i=0; i<test.size(); ++i) {
cout << test[i] <<< " | ";
}
```

Comment: > `int *test = new int[];`
> 
> Эта строка эквивалентна следующей
> 
> `int *test = new int;`

Вы уверены? По-моему, она вообще не должна компилироваться.

Comment: Да, действительно. Спасибо за поправку.

Хотя, вы знаете, в отличии от GCC 4.8.1, MSVS2010 мне это простил. IntelliSence-ошибкой мне сообщил, что "incomplete type is not allowed", но собрался без ворнингов даже.

Comment: @Free_ze, интересно, а на что указывает `test` после `int *test = new int[];`?

    cout << "addr: " << test << '\n';


Попробуйте также `malloc_usable_size(test)` (в винде м.б. надо заменить `_msize()`).

Comment: Нормальный ненулевой адрес. _msize возвращает 0.

Comment: @Free_ze, да, у ребят из M$ с логикой все отлично...

Подумать только, выделять область памяти **нулевой длины!**

Недаром глюкавость так распространена в этой системе.

Answer (score 0):

я вижу несколько ошибок :

1. в цикле надо следить за тем, что не достигли конца файла
2. не закрываете файл
3. вы либо задаете массиву сразу размер , либо расширяете его по ходу программы с помощью **realloc**(но тогда инициализировать как вы сделали, незя)
4. не удаляете руками ссылку